# SQL Query to find last segment of a directory path

Tags: sql

What is the SQL syntax to find last directory segment of a file path and use `substring` to extract the name.

**Input:**
` '/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2'

I want the name of last directory used i.e. C `

**Output:**
`c`

Comment: Do you really want to substring `C` or did you mean `Directory_C`?

Comment: Name of last occurrence of Directory i.e. C

Comment: Why can't you use simply `RIGHT` function?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And why wouldn't the last "directory" be `folder1`?

Comment: I am using SQL server.. and I need to perform search only till Directory level not Folder level.

Comment: I think you are looking for this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961729/fetch-element-at-particular-position/56961985#56961985

Answer (score 0):

Use `RIGHT` function.

**Query**

```
select RIGHT('/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C', 1);
```

Comment: Sorry For not providing full details but input can be like this also: '/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2'. I want the name of last directory used i.e. C

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL [`RIGHT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_right.asp) and [`LOWER`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_lower.asp):

```
SELECT LOWER(RIGHT('/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C', 1));
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/93413)

Comment: Sorry For not providing full details but input can be like this also: '/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2'. I want the name of last directory used i.e. C